# How do I make an image resize with browser height?

Tags: html, css, image, browser

**Edit 1:** I thought I'd clarify my post. Basically, I want my photo to resize relative to browser window height, but always leave a `margin-bottom` of approx. `40px` between it and the bottom of the page. However, it doesn't work. Instead, the browser makes sure it can accomodate the whole image, so it extends the page below where it should end.

**The confusing part, sorry:** I have an image that is set to resize according to browser height. The image does resize (I've given all ancestors `height:100%`, and the image `height:98%`, but it soon gets to a point where the whole image is no longer visible, as it is too large to fit the page. The easiest way to fix this would be to reduce the image's height to a smaller percentage value, but I don't want to.

I have an absolutely positioned footer at the bottom of the page, which proves to be problematic. My original thought was to set the image's `margin-bottom` (or `padding-bottom`) to `20px` (which is the same distance between my top menu and the image) so there was a gap between my footer and the image at all times, even when the browser was resized. But obviously this isn't going to work, as the footer is absolutely positioned.

My other idea was to set a `px` height to `body` or `html`, but this won't work either, as if a user has a screen larger than this, the page will be limited to the `px` height. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Below is a screenshot of what my problem looks like. The copyright etc is the footer, which is actually at the bottom of the page, but the image has pushed this bottom a little further.

[image]

Oh, I also wanted to add, is it possible to set the image to resize depending on both height and width, using % factors?

Comment: Can you show your code or give a demo?

Comment: @Jonathan - I added an image. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Then is your issue about the footer, not the image? You want the footer to stay at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Without having the specific html and css, your question is a little too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been unclear. The footer does stay at the bottom of the page, despite what the image shows. My problem is that I want the image to stay between the footer and the top menu (not pictures), but because the footer is absolutely positioned, I don't know how I'm going to go about doing it.

Comment: Why is your footer absolutely positioned?

Comment: @fauxserious, it's a "trick" for keeping the footer positioned at the bottom of the page. Refer to Uniforlyff's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are units that handle percent of the viewport height and width using `vw` and `vh` respectively so that.

```
img{
   height:100vh;
}
```

This make all img elements 100% of the viewport (window) height.

Comment: This is a relatively new attribute and because of that, older browsers will not support this.

Comment: I didn't read any compatibility requirements so I figured it would be acceptable.

Comment: I'm not the OP but this is a good answer, `vh` is an awesome attribute that is coming more into light with more browser support.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh Microsoft is slacking as usual.

Comment: That works brilliantly. Thank you @fauxserious.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem you're encountering is that the footer doesn't stay at the bottom of the page. You've absolutely positioned it, and it's not moving even when the image is. The image is moving correctly (correct?)

You can set the footer to move with browser resize to fix this issue. This would be easiest in jQuery, if you are using it (but possible in JS):

```
$(document).resize(function() {
    $("#FOOTER_ID_HERE").css("top", $(document).height() - 20);
});
```

As for your second question, it is possible to set the image to a certain height and width in percentage (and resize as its container does).

Comment: Sorry, I must have been unclear. The footer does stay at the bottom of the page, despite what the image shows. My problem is that I want the image to stay between the footer and the top menu (not pictures), but because the footer is absolutely positioned, I don't know how I'm going to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <small>Copyright &copy; Tim Conn Photography 2015. All rights reserved.</small>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; /* footer will always be in the bottom even when resized */
    padding: 40px 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have been unclear. The footer does stay at the bottom of the page, despite what the image shows. My problem is that I want the image to stay between the footer and the top menu (not pictures), but because the footer is absolutely positioned, I don't know how I'm going to go about doing it.

Comment: check this, I'm not really sure since I'm kind of confuse but I wanted to help. http://output.jsbin.com/yibate/5

Comment: maybe check my Edit 1 (in the OP) to see if that helps clarifying things?